Getting connection error while trying to create an SSRS report in VS2019
I'm getting a connection error while trying to create a DataSet from my DataSource in Visual Studio. Below is the error I get when I try to go into the Query Designer while in the Shared Dataset Properties. See image
Here is my connection string from the Shared DataSource Properties window.
Data Source=DESKTOP-RDA02NR\SQLSERVERID;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorksLT2012;
I checked the login credentials and didn't see anything abnormal.

Assuming this is just a test/dev setup (as it looks like your sql server is running on a desktop) then you could try just adding ;TrustServerCertificate=True to the end of connection string.

"The certificate received from the remote server was issued by an untrusted certificate authority" error when you connect to SQL Server
